# Grunt watch doesn't run

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I've been having trouble figuring out how to run grunt-contrib-watch. Running `grunt watch` as specified only results in:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Then I'm back at my command prompt again, with no watch process blocking the input, or showing up in Task Manager; and I've been messing with this since last night and still can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Here's my [gruntfile](http://pastebin.com/M5hspMYD); I'm working on a Windows 7 machine, if that's any help.

Comment: Try with `grunt watch -v`. That will enable verbose output and show all the files it is watching. If you're still having issues could you open it up on https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues?

Comment: Here's the output I get: http://pastebin.com/2905MdzC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed your gruntfile has `filed` where it should be `files`:

```
watch: {
  filed: ['src/**/*'],
  tasks: ['stylus:compile', 'coffee:compile', 'jade:compile'],
}
```

Try this instead:

```
watch: {
  files: ['src/**/*'],
  tasks: ['stylus:compile', 'coffee:compile', 'jade:compile'],
}
```